# Django ArrayField Filtering with contains matching

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using Django Postgres ArrayField

```
response_headers = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True),blank=True,null=True,default=list)
```

Let's suppose our object has the  following data:

```
obj1 : response_headers = ["dubai","sydney","nyc"]
obj2 : response_headers = ["mumbai","kerela","dubai"]
```

```
MyModel.objects.filter(response_headers__contains=['dubai']
```

would return `obj1` & `obj2` but

```
MyModel.objects.filter(response_headers__contains=['duba']
   or 
MyModel.objects.filter(response_headers__contains=['uba']
```

won't return any objects `<QuerySet []>`

How do I achieve the ability to search with the partial pattern across all indexes of ArrayField?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, only exact element matching is possible.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(response_headers__contains=['duba'])
```

Will perform exact match search using postgresql  contains `@>` operator.

---

However, a hacky option exists which may be suitable if ArrayField contains only simple strings:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(response_headers__icontains='duba')
```

this will cast `ArrayField` to text, uppercase it and perform `LIKE '%DUBA%'`.

So, it is not checking if there is any element (i)like 'duba' in array, but translates array into one string (and if elements are not simple strings - result may be undesirable) - i.e. `{dubai,sydney,nyc}` and then performs case-insensitive match of it with argument `duba`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it as far as I'm aware of, you can search inside a specific item of the array using the [index transform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#index-transforms) but you can't look into every single item at once.

It's probably worth to create a new model for your response headers and filter using the relation, something like this:

```py
class Header(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Response(models.Model):
    ...
    headers = models.ManyToManyField(Header)


responses = Response.objects.filter(headers__value__contains='duba')
```